# How to fix Connection to localhost:5432 refused in postgres installed on CentOS 7?

Tags: spring, postgresql, centos

I have a digitalocean droplet and I'm trying to install my Java web-application, on CentOS 7, which is using postgres database. I've successfully installed Java, tomcat and postgres database. I am able to connect to my droplet's postgres database from my local machine using pgadmin as well as from local eclipse. But when I am deploying the web application on server I'm getting the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I've added listen_addresses = '*' to postgresql.conf

This is the code from pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Is there any firewall issue? Do I need to provide any special permission? The port which I am using to connect is 5432. I've not made any changes to the port.

I deleted the droplet and installed ubuntu 18 on it, I was successfully able to connect to the database properly. Again, I installed CentOS 7 and it gives the same problem.

Here's the output of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

sestatus

```
 SELinux status:                 enabled
    SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
    SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
    Loaded policy name:             targeted
    Current mode:                   enforcing
    Mode from config file:          enforcing
    Policy MLS status:              enabled
    Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
    Max kernel policy version:      31
```

Comment: I assume, your java application and postgres run on the same host and they don't run in containers. Can you add the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: Yes they run on the same host. I've updated the question with the results.

Comment: It seems to me something like a selinux issue. Could you please run the command `sestatus` to check?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: Then you should try to disable selinux temporarily in order to check it will solve the problem or not. Try this command as root `setenforce 0`. This should disable it temporarily.

Comment: Doing this fixed it. But what is the problem here? Is it safe to do this?

Comment: I do not know in detail for the security aspect but I suffered this a lot when I use centos 7 or higher for my servers. For better solution it is more appropriate to just allow for web server access to postgresql tcp port instead of disabling it totally. I could not follow in time but @paulrichards321's answer will probably solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason my tomcat 8 server just did that the same thing this morning, when it was working previously. I looked at the selinux logs in /var/log/audit and found the following got me back working again:

sudo setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db true

Edited: added -P flag to stick between reboots.

Comment: I totally agree my comment was just about testing purposes. By the way -P flag may be needed because you probably want to persist this setting across reboots. Like this `sudo setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db true`

Comment: setenforce 1; also sudo vi or sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux to make sure it's permanent. Reference: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-redhat-how-to-set-selinux-modes/

Comment: Good to know Yavuz! I most have left out the -P previously because I think I did it on the previous reboot and the option didn't stick.